# How to get the text elements from python dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, tweepy

I am trying to get some content from pandas column. The pandas dataframe is df and have a column named entities. This column seem to contain dictionaries. One of them is 'hashtags', which contains another dictionary 'text'. There can be multiple 'text' elements in a single row. Want to get the values for text field. The example below can help to understand.
It will be helpful if I can get guidance on getting the hashtags values.

```
df['entities']
```

output =>

```
0  {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1460865425911205891', 'display_url': 'twitter.com/i/web/status/1…', 'indices': [117, 140]}]}
1  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'carbon', 'indices': [17, 24]}, {'text': 'nature', 'indices': [48, 55]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https://rpujolviven.blogspot.com/2012/10/infinite-growth.html', 'display_url': 'rpujolviven.blogspot.com/2012/10/infini…', 'indices': [61, 84]}, {'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https...
2  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Lincoln', 'indices': [69, 77]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https://thelincolnite.co.uk/2021/11/professor-duncan-french-the-juggernaut-of-climate-politics-rolls-on/', 'display_url': 'thelincolnite.co.uk/2021/11/profes…', 'indices': [78, 101]}]}
3  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'CBDC', 'indices': [107, 112]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': , 'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1460865388699344900', 'display_url': 'twitter.com/i/web/status/1…', 'indices': [115, 138]}]}
```

The expected output:

```
 0  []
 1  ['carbon', 'nature']
 2  ['Lincoln']
 3  ['CBDC']
```

Answer (score 1):

try `df['entities'].map(lambda x:[i['text'] for i in x['hashtags']])`.

Details (I used Google colab):

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.Series([ {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1460865425911205891', 'display_url': 'twitter.com/i/web/status/1…', 'indices': [117, 140]}]}
,{'hashtags': [{'text': 'carbon', 'indices': [17, 24]}, {'text': 'nature', 'indices': [48, 55]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https://rpujolviven.blogspot.com/2012/10/infinite-growth.html', 'display_url': 'rpujolviven.blogspot.com/2012/10/infini…', 'indices': [61, 84]}, {'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https...'}]}
,{'hashtags': [{'text': 'Lincoln', 'indices': [69, 77]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https://thelincolnite.co.uk/2021/11/professor-duncan-french-the-juggernaut-of-climate-politics-rolls-on/', 'display_url': 'thelincolnite.co.uk/2021/11/profes…', 'indices': [78, 101]}]}
,{'hashtags': [{'text': 'CBDC', 'indices':[107, 112]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1460865388699344900', 'display_url': 'twitter.com/i/web/status/1…', 'indices': [115, 138]}]}])
df = a.to_frame(name="entities")
df['entities']
df['entities'].map(lambda x:[i['text'] for i in x['hashtags']])
```

Output:

```
0    {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions...
1    {'hashtags': [{'text': 'carbon', 'indices': [1...
2    {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Lincoln', 'indices': [...
3    {'hashtags': [{'text': 'CBDC', 'indices': [107...
Name: entities, dtype: object

0                  []
1    [carbon, nature]
2           [Lincoln]
3              [CBDC]
Name: entities, dtype: object
```

Reference:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am getting the following error if I execute the above.     

    <ipython-input-7-0137d5246743> in <lambda>(x)
      2 #tweets['hashtags'].apply(lambda x: [d['text'] for d in x])
      3 pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 400)
----> 4 df['entities'].map(lambda x:[i['text'] for i in x['hashtags']])

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to pinpoint which data row is causing the error? Cause I tried with your data (the 4 data rows) in your post and it works fine for me. What I am guessing is some data rows may not follow the format you have given in the post.

Comment: I also edited my answer to show my code details, hope that helps.